# Eclipse won't let me create AVD

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, eclipse-plugin, android-virtual-device

When I try to create an AVD through Eclipse, it won't let me click the ok button because it does not supply a list of CPUs. When I try to do this outside of Eclipse, the AVD will successfully build, but when I try to use it in Eclipse, it is listed as unrepairable. Any suggestions?

Comment: could You make a screenshot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem.  I had the SDK, but not the emulators.  Go to Window -> SDK manager. I'm going to bet you have the SDK tools, but not the Android x.x.x emulator packages.  Pick your emulators, install, restart Eclipse and try again.